# Error while using two EntityManagers simultaneously in GlassFish v2

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I have a stateless session bean (slsb) that has a dependency on two other beans that act as DAOs. They both use JPA so each bean has a `EntityManager`. They point to different persistence units (which in turn are different connection pools to the same database - I don't want to sacrifice this flexibility).

In simple code it looks like this (the names in my application are real names of course):

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {
    @EJB
    private Dao1 dao1;

    @EJB
    private Dao2 dao2;
}

@Stateless
public class Dao1 {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "unit1")
    private EntityManager em1;
}

@Stateless
public class Dao2 {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "unit2")
    private EntityManager em2;
}
```

When I access methods of both `Dao1` and `Dao2` in `MyBean` I invariably get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Unable to complete container-managed transaction.; nested exception is: javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: JTS5031: Exception [org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0 completed: Maybe] on Resource [rollback] operation.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
javax.ejb.EJBException: Unable to complete container-managed transaction.; nested exception is: javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: JTS5031: Exception [org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0 completed: Maybe] on Resource [rollback] operation.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: JTS5031: Exception [org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0 completed: Maybe] on Resource [rollback] operation.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:321)
    at com.sun.enterprise.distributedtx.J2EETransactionManagerImpl.commit(J2EETransactionManagerImpl.java:1029)
    at com.sun.enterprise.distributedtx.J2EETransactionManagerOpt.commit(J2EETransactionManagerOpt.java:398)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:3826)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:3605)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1388)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1325)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:83)
    at $Proxy280.anotherMethod(Unknown Source)
    at com.mycompany.SomeClass.someMethod(SomeClass.java:256)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.InstanceResolverImpl$1.invoke(InstanceResolverImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:106)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:106)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe$1.run(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:236)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:444)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:177)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor419.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:420)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:666)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:872)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
javax.ejb.EJBException: Unable to complete container-managed transaction.; nested exception is: javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: JTS5031: Exception [org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0 completed: Maybe] on Resource [rollback] operation.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:3837)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:3605)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1388)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1325)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:83)
    at $Proxy280.anotherMethod(Unknown Source)
    at com.mycompany.SomeClass.someMethod(SomeClass.java:256)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.InstanceResolverImpl$1.invoke(InstanceResolverImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:106)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:106)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe$1.run(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:236)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:444)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:177)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor419.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:420)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:666)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:872)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
```

After turning the verbosity of loggers *CORBA*, *EJB Container*, *JTA* and *JTS* to *FINEST* the following lines appear directly before the exception:

```
FINEST: Before invoking before_completion() on synchronization object com.sun.jts.jta.SynchronizationImpl@7a352e18
FINEST: After invoking before_completion() on synchronization object com.sun.jts.jta.SynchronizationImpl@7a352e18
FINEST: Acquiring read lock on freeze : state PREPARING
FINEST: Acquired read lock on freeze : state PREPARING
FINER: Before invoking prepare() on resource:OTSResource : XAResource com.sun.gjc.spi.XAResourceImpl@179e50a5 XID {XID: formatID(4871251), gtrid_length(29), bqual_length(23), data(3D000000 43EF313F 70632D77 6861686E 2C736572 7665722C 50333730 3070632D 77686168 6E2C7365 72766572 2C503337 30302C00)}
FINE: An XAException occurred in prepare
```

Nothing else (except thousands of `FINE: TM: enlistComponentResources` and `FINE: TM: delistResource` but they look normal).

Both connection pools are configured as `XADataSource`. My current workaround is that one of the two DAOs sports this annotation:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

I don't think this is a good solution but I don't know how to fix it otherwise. Can I get rid of this error in a better way?

Comment: The error is totally cryptic... Don't you get anything more useful in the server.log? Did you try to increase logging verbosity?

Comment: @Pascal: I increased the logging levels of a few relevant loggers and updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping to get more details. Hard to say what is causing this XAException...

Comment: Can you have more than one active transaction per EM? I know you can have nested transactions. However, I bet you're running into problems because you have transactions spanning both em's and when the second transaction comes along it wants exclusive access to the EM.

Comment: @Preston: This may be true. I don't know how common my requirement is but I think I need it. To elaborate: One EM is responsible for business data while the other EM provides configuration data for the application. I would like to keep that distinction. Right now I can live with the workaround but of course I want to avoid this problem in potentially bigger projects in the future.